# Role of eqn3 in Fipy examples.cahnHilliard.mesh2DCoupled

Tags: python, numerical-methods, fipy

I am currently working through the examples in the fipy documentation and am trying to adapt the `examples.cahnHilliard.mesh2DCoupled` to perform some simulations. The link is : https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/cahnHilliard/generated/examples.cahnHilliard.mesh2DCoupled.html

It seems that the example code declares an `eq3` and a `dfdphi_` and does not use these equations anywhere else, even in the solution.

From the documentation:

```
>>> D = a = epsilon = 1.
>>> dfdphi = a**2 * phi * (1 - phi) * (1 - 2 * phi)
>>> dfdphi_ = a**2 * (1 - phi) * (1 - 2 * phi)
>>> d2fdphi2 = a**2 * (1 - 6 * phi * (1 - phi))
>>> eq1 = (TransientTerm(var=phi) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D, var=psi))
>>> eq2 = (ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=1., var=psi)
...        == ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=d2fdphi2, var=phi) - d2fdphi2 * phi + dfdphi
...        - DiffusionTerm(coeff=epsilon**2, var=phi))
>>> eq3 = (ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=1., var=psi)
...        == ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=dfdphi_, var=phi)
...        - DiffusionTerm(coeff=epsilon**2, var=phi))
>>> eq = eq1 & eq2
```

and in the solution block:

```
>>> while elapsed < duration:
...     dt = min(100, numerix.exp(dexp))
...     elapsed += dt
...     dexp += 0.01
...     eq.solve(dt=dt)
...     if __name__ == "__main__":
...         viewer.plot()
```

I would appreciate any insight regarding what the `eq3` and `dfdphi_` terms do. And as an extension to that, how does the solver know to use the old values of $\phi$ to evaluate the linearised form after taylor expression since the solver block does not seem to account for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eqn2` and `eqn3` encode, in the limit of infinitesimal time and space steps, the same equation. However, in their discretization they single out different terms for a more active role in the construction of the time step propagator.

In the short term this should only lead to insignificant differences in the result, in the long term there may be more pronounced differences in stability and accuracy.

That the "more natural" equation `eq3` is present at all seems to be an indirect invitation to experiment with it, and perhaps to explore if the transformation in `eq2` with its possible advantages is a coincidence or result of some more deeply founded idea.